# "Convert" package to load in Symfony

Tags: php, package, symfony

I have [THIS](https://github.com/sofort/sofortlib-php) package (a payment gateway), which I would like to use in Symfony 3.0.1
Unfortunately I get this error:

> ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 21: Attempted to load class "SofortBundle" from namespace "Sofort\SofortLib".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

In the `sofort\sofortlib-php` folder i created the file `SofortBundle.php` with this content

```
<?php

  namespace Sofort\SofortLib;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle as BaseBundle;

 class SofortBundle extends BaseBundle
 {
 }
```

and I loaded the Bundle in `AppKernel.php`:

```
new Sofort\SofortLib\SofortBundle(),
```

But that only leads to above exception.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this a project you started with Symfony 3 or did you upgrade an existing Symfony 2 application?

Comment: started with smyfony3

Comment: Can you show your `composer.json` configuration?

Comment: The error mean that you have bundle in wrong folder, the `SofortBundle.php` file should be in `src/Sofort/SofortLib/SofortBundle.php`, but it isn't correct way to include composer packages, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't copy packages to your custom folder. Install package as described:

In `composer.json` add:

```
 "require": {
    "sofort/sofortlib-php": "3.*"
}
```

Run `composer update sofort/sofortlib-php`

In your code you can use the library like this:

```
use \Sofort\SofortLib\Billcode;

class MyClass
{
    function doSomething($configkey) {

        $SofortLibBillcode = new Billcode($configkey);

        ...
    }
}
```